# Dynamically add TableLayout to LinearLayout + remove just loaded TableLayout from LinearLayout and load it again give error

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a question about my LinearLayout with a nested `TableLayout`.
The `TableLayout` gets filled  with rows cols filled with ImageViews dynamically.
see function `addImagesToTableLayout()`

In fact, everything is working when I  start the  application. LinearLayout get loaded with nested TableLayout nested with ImageViews
What I would like to accomplish is that when clicking one of the images all the images in the parent `TableLayout` inclusive `TableLayout by its self` must removed completely. 
So i can add a new fresh `TableLayout` to my `LinearLayout`

Removing is not the problem, the problem is when i call addImagesToTableLayout();
second time thus after removing, i got this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must
call   removeView() on the child's parent first.


 private void addImagesToTableLayout(ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewCollection){

        tablelayout =  new TableLayout(this);
        LayoutParams param = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param.weight = 2.0f;
        param.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        param.leftMargin = portraitmargin - (sqr) ;

        tablelayout.setLayoutParams(param); 
        tableRows = new TableRow[levelNumber-1];

        int m = 0;//modulo
        int i = 0;
        int f = 0;

        for (ImageView s : imageViewCollection)
        {
            m = (i) % sqr;  

            if (m == 0){

                 tableRows[f] = new TableRow(this);  
                 tableRows[f].setId(f+1);
                 f++;     
             } 

             tableRows[f-1].addView(imageViewCollection.get(i));
             i++;
        }

         for(int j = 0; j < sqr; j++) {

        tableRows[j].setLayoutParams(new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     tableRows[j].setWeightSum(1.0f); 
                     tablelayout.addView(tableRows[j]);
         }

         linearlayout.addView(tablelayout);
 }


// remove tablelayout                   
linearlayout.removeAllViews();

if(linearlayout.getChildCount() == 0) {
  // add a new TableLayout to my root linearLayout (gives error see above)
  addImagesToTableLayout(imageViewCollection);
}
```

Comment: I would give you a down, simply because your title has nothing to do with the question...

I waisted 3-4 minutes to answer the title's question just to catch a glimpse of your code and see you actually know how to add a tableLayout to a LinearLayout... which is what is "asked" in your title...

Learn to post proper titles with your question(s).

Comment: Sorry Vlad your right but if you read well furher i think iam clear,anyway i change the title

Comment: Yea ,you are right also.It was my bad that I looked superficially on your code...

Anyways, I guess I have answered your question, hopefully.

If you need more details, let me know via comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = tablelayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
   View v = tablelayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof TableRow){
    TableRow row = (TableRow)v;
       int rowCount = row.getChildCount();
         for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++){
           View v2 = row.getChildAt(r);
              if (v2 instanceof Button){
               Button b = (Button)v2;
               b.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener ...//add the mehtod yourself please,I always use eclipse's hints,I forgot exactly how the method looks, but it's a method that has a View v as parameter );
        }
    }
}
```

So, I am adding a clickListener to each "cell" of your table.

This would be a solution to achieve what you want,although, if you got many images, adding a listener to each one, ain't the best solution -but it works.

Also, inside the onClickListener's method, you need to add the line of code that removes your stuff form the table.This one:

```
tablelayout.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, i think my question is not clear, my removeViews code is standing in my onClickhandler. My setOnClickListener is somewhere else in my code declared but not relevant for my question. MyQuestion: What I would like to accomplish is that when clicking one of the images all the images in the parent TableLayout inclusive TableLayout are removed completely. So i can add a new fresh TableLayout to my LinearLayout. So far i see adding and removing are succesful but adding new tablelaout to linearlaout give the error message.